# How to read all the text files in the subfolders and add the file content (a four digit number) to a list?

Tags: python, tuples, text-files, createfile, empty-list

I'm learning python, and I'm trying to read all text files in the subfolders I have, and add the file content (a four-digit number) to a list. I only want to read files with a file extension .txt.

I tried:

```py
import os
path = "C:\python_projects\PythonProgramming\data-task1\q6" (example)
os.chdir(path)

def read_text_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())

for file in os.listdir():  
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        file_path = f"{path}\{file}"
    
        read_text_file(file_path)
```

Can you please help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: What is the exect problem?

Comment: Hello TDG, I can't extract the content. The text files have 4 digits, like a year 2003 for example, and the code run but I can't understand how can extract the numbers

Answer (score 0):

From your current code, you should just add the list and conversion like so:

```py
    import os
    path = "C:\python_projects\PythonProgramming\data-task1\q6" # Example.
    os.chdir(path)
    
    def read_text_file(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            return f.read()
    
    numbers = []
    for file in os.listdir():  
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            file_path = f"{path}\{file}"
    
            numbers.append(int(read_text_file(file_path)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a function, that can be used recursively to go through all folders and subfolders

```
from os import listdir, chdir
from os.path import isdir

path = r"C:\users\me\whatever\path"
chdir(path)
numbers = []

def read_text_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        return f.read()

def checkFolder(path):
    for file is listdir(path):
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            file_path = f"{path}\{file}"
            numbers.append(int(read_text_file(file_path)))
        elif isdir(f"{path}\{file}"): #Checks if the file is a directory
            checkFolder(f"{path}\{file}") #Re-run the function with the next subfolder

checkFolder(path)
```